# Getting a "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk4\DR4". Why?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, drivers, controller

I'm getting errors like this showing up in my event log:

> The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk4\DR4.

It's for drives DR1 to DR4. On my PC that's things like MicroSD drives and so on. It's not on my primary hard drive, which is DR0. And as it so happens I don't have any MicroSD card in the drive.

So why am I getting errors on these drives from the controller, when there is no removable drive in any of them?

Comment: It means your MicroSD reader is likely failing.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thank you. Then I suppose there's nothing I can do about it. The machine is about 4 years old, so after a while things fail.